# What do battery numbers mean? E.g., 26R-5N

Tags: battery, dodge, neon

I went to Walmart and put my car's information (2000 Dodge Neon) into the electronic battery selector, and it told me to purchase a 26R-5N battery (which matches my current battery).

However, what do these numbers mean?  From what I gather, the R indicates "reverse", meaning that the terminals are reversed.  Some batteries online are listed as 26R with no 5N.  Is that significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

26 - Battery Group size (determines the dimensions of the battery: https://www.jegs.com/Sizecharts/bcigroup.html)

R - You are correct, this means the terminals are reversed.

5N - Not sure what this part means!

Comment: N Stands for Newton which is a force. 1N = 1kg m/s2 (force required to accelerate 1kg at 1m/s)